# Hibernate: Insert issue - Parent Key not found

Tags: hibernate

I am facing issue inserting an entity into database. I am using Hibernate JPA.
Here is my database structure :

```
Table : User {CGU_USER_ID as PK}
Table : Industries {CGI_INDUSTRY_ID (PK),CGI_INDUSTRY_NAME}
Table : USER_INDUSTRY_MAP {CUIM_USER_ID (FK),CUIM_INDUSTRY_ID (FK)}
```

Here is my Mapping :

```
@JoinTable(name = "USER_INDUSTRY_MAP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CUIM_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CGU_USER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CUIM_INDUSTRY_ID"))
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Industry> industrySet;
```

The Exception i am getting says :

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert collection: [com.keff.gg.domain.User.industrySet#1242]; SQL [insert into CG_USER_INDUSTRY_MAP (CUIM_USER_ID, CUIM_INDUSTRY_ID) values (?, ?)]; constraint [CUSTOMERGATEWAY.FK_CUIM_USER_ID]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert collection: [com.keff.gg.domain.User.industrySet#1242]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (CUSTOMERPROJECT.FK_CUIM_USER_ID) violated - parent key not found
```

Here is my insert code:

```
User user = new User();
query = session.createQuery("from Industry industry where industry.industryName=:industryName");
        query.setParameter("industryName", "validIndstry");
        results = (List<?>) query.list();
        if(results != null && results.size()>0){
            industryList = (List<Industry>)results;
        }
user.setIndustrySet(industryList); // If this is set to null then insert into User table is successfull
Long id = (Long) hibernateTemplate.save(user);
```

Can somebody look at my mappings and tell me what i am doing wrong. 
Please help me out. I am very very new to hibernate. Please let me know if more information is required to trace the issue.

UPDATE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I have tried Making the relationship Many to many and bidirectional

```
//User Class
@JoinTable(name = "CG_USER_INDUSTRY_MAP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CUIM_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CGU_USER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CUIM_INDUSTRY_ID"))
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Industry> industrySet;

//Industry Class
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "industrySet")
private List<User> userSet;
```

But still getting the same issue.

Comment: Why do you have a `@OneToMany` relation and the relationship table that is usually used for `@ManyToMany` relations?

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks for quick response. I understand that there should have been only two tables with Industries holding the FK of Users. I am not sure why the database design is like that. but I will not be able to change that. Shouldn't it work this way?

Comment: The mapping is fine. It's actually the default way a OneToMany unidirectional association is mapped.

Comment: Try saving the user first, and then setting its collection of industries. Also, are all these industries not referenced by any other user? Because if they are, then it's a ManyToMany association, and not a OneToMany.

Comment: Thanks Nizet, I tried doing that. But still i am getting the same issue. Also I made the relationship many to many. still no gain. Any other pointers will be most helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I found out the root cause of the issue i was facing.

There was a trigger on the User table that was updating the User sequence after each insert. 
I guess that was causing the issue. I can see that after disabling the trigger I am able to save the User entity correctly without any issues.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Thanks this is also the cause of my issue, i was unaware of my co-dev added a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a persist operation make sure you have the cascade option on your mapping.  You can add CascadeType.PERSIST to your persist options to get this to work.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {  CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE ,CascadeType.PERSIST })
@JoinTable(name = "USER_INDUSTRY_MAP", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CUIM_USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CUIM_INDUSTRY_ID") })
private List<Industry> industries = new ArrayList<Industry>();
```

You can even use CascadeType.ALL to specify that all operations should be cascaded for an association.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But that didn't helped .I am still getting the same issue.